# Get twilio usage data using an AWS Lambda (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, twilio, twilio-api

I would like to be able to get usage data from Twilio from within an AWS Lambda function.  I am following the examples on twilio's REST API [page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record) but am not having any success. I am using version 3 of Twilio's Node Helper Library.  Below is the code that I have in the handler:

```
    'use strict';
    exports.handler = async(request, context) => {
        const accountSid = 'my account sid'; 
        const authToken = 'my auth token'; 
        const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
        client.usage.records.today.each(record => console.log(record.count));
    };
```

The Lambda "feels" like it is at least trying to get the data from Twilio.  It runs for ~10 seconds before ending without any errors.  However I never get the 'here' message.

Thanks in advance, Scott

Comment: I am running the lambda manually in the AWS console.  I have the lambda's timeout set to 30 seconds.  Here is the output:

Function Logs:

END RequestId: b0c1d674-ba92-4a2c-8ed0-6cc9cf52e22d

REPORT RequestId: b0c1d674-ba92-4a2c-8ed0-6cc9cf52e22d Duration: 11034.23 ms Billed Duration: 11100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB Init Duration: 463.96 ms

Comment: Increase memory, 128 MB might not be enough.

Comment: I just saw that as I was reviewing my comment.  I will let you know what happens.

Comment: @AlexBaban Set the lambda to max memory (3008 MB).  The lambda now executes in 700ms, uses 143 MB of memory.  Still not getting any output.

Comment: Do you have anything in the "Execution Result" tab (underneath function code editor)?

Comment: Nope.  I don't return anything from the lambda so the Response is null.  For Logs I have just the entries that AWS inserts (the START, END and REPORT log entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my Lambda code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
    const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;

    // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console
    const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

    // Import Twilio's Node Helper library
    // Create an authenticated Twilio Client instance
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

    client.usage.records.lastMonth.each(record => console.log('here'));


};
```

---

and this is what I see in the "Function code" section after I run the function (Status: Succeeded).

[image]

Comment: OK, my Lambda was using async function.  I didn't see anywhere in the twilio docs that this was for non-async functions.

Thanks Alex!